# Validating id recieved with regular expression

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm trying to get ID from URL (in django):

```
url(r'^preset/(P<pk>\d+)$', views.route_preset_api.as_view()),
```

This works well as long as the input is a number. But if it isn't a number the page will return a 500 error.

How can I do a special case, that will take care of all non-valid inputs and will give for example

```
pk=0
```

as an output?

Comment: No, a non-number input will give a 404 error, because it won't match `\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

First of all your pattern is missing a required `?` which specifies a named group. It should be:

```
r'^preset/(?P<pk>\d+)$'
```

which will associate the matched substring with the group name `pk`, i.e. a named group. Without the `?` the regex will literally match `preset/P<pk>` followed by 1 or more digits.

Secondly, the regex will not match if any non-digit is present, and a 404 Not Found response will be sent. Possibly the 500 error is occurring elsewhere in your code - is there a less specific pattern that is matching?

To handle invalid requests you could add a second pattern that routes to the same view function, but add a default argument for the `pk` parameter. The URL pattern would be:

```
url(r'^preset/[^\d]*$', views.route_preset_api.as_view()),
```

and the view function would look something like this:

```
def route_preset_api(request, pk=0):
    ...
```

Now `pk` will default to `0` whenever a request is made that contains a non-digit character.